# How do I calculate a vertex's position on the CPU?

Tags: opengl, c++

I'm creating light processor and I need light position and vertex position after translating, rotating and scaling (to calculate distance between them to check if light is affecting my vertex somehow).

But my question is how to properly multiply my position in Vector3 with transformation matrix to get real vertex position in the world?

To calculate it in GLSL I just simply use something like this:

```
vec4 vertexInWorldPosition = transformMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition,1.0);
```

But how properly do that with my vertex (Stored in Vector3) and Matrix4 in C++ code? Do I need to multiply each row or column by my original `vertexPosition` stored to Vector4? I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do exactly the same thing. You have an initial (mode space) position as a 3-component vector, turn it into a 4-component vector by setting the 4th component to 1.0.

Then you have the model-to-world transformation matrix in a 4x4 matrix instance, so you can perform [matrix multiplication](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) of the 4x4 matrix with the 4x1 "matrix" that is the vector. Most math libraries that provide matrix and vector types also implement this multiplication operation for you, allowing you to write 'result = transformMatrix * initialVector' or similar.

If your math library does not you'll need to [implement the operation](http://mathinsight.org/matrix_vector_multiplication) yourself. The product of a matrix 'M' and a (column) vector v (on the right, as in your example) is equivalent to a series of dot products of the rows of M with v. The new x component is dot(row 0, v). The new y component is dot(row 1, v), and so on.

Comment: and I can compare my vec4 with light position in vec3 by creating another vec4 with light position and set w to 1.0?

Comment: Yes, generally, unless you have done something abnormal in your world transformation such that the transformed w component is no longer 1.0